# vim NERDTree key mapping

Tags: vim, nerdtree

```
" ==== NERD tree
" Cmd-Shift-N for nerd tree
nmap <D-N> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
" Open the project tree and expose current file in the nerdtree with Ctrl-\
nnoremap <silent> <C-\> :NERDTreeFind<CR>:vertical res 30<CR>
```

I probably not understand that key mapping means:

```
`nmap <D-N>` maps `D` - Mac Command key ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<D-…>` is the Command key on Mac OS X. That key can only be seen by the MacVim GUI.

- That mapping does nothing outside of the MacVim GUI,
- copying settings from someone else's `vimrc` is not a very good idea.

See `:help key-notation`.